# In C, why does "int MAX = 10^6...int arr[MAX]" not crash, but "int MAX = 1000000...int arr[MAX]" does crash?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm currently using C and ran into something I found interesting, but can't seem to find anything that was similar on here.

I am statically allocating memory for an array (size 1000000). I know this is quite large and has potential to cause problems. But, using 10^6 causes no problems, while 1000000 causes a crash, likely due to the massive size. I was wondering if there are any limitations that might come up if I continue with 10^6.

```
int main() {
    int i, n, MAX = 10^6; //change 10^6 to 1000000 to cause crash
    int highest, newHighest, lowest, profit, newProfit;
    int arr[MAX];

    return 0;
}
```

I have confirmed that my code is crashing at line 4. Any information would be appreciated.

Thanks

***edit for semicolon

Comment: Do `printf("%i\n", 10^6)` for a surprise.

Comment: Interesting...How does this occur though? The size of the array that I am using is 14, and I am having no problems running, so what is happening to "10^6 = 12"?

Comment: u can't allocate an array of size `1000000 ` on stack memory, use malloc

Comment: also, you need a `;` after `int i,n,MAX=10^6`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int i, n, MAX = 10^6 //change 10^6 to 1000000 to cause crash;
```

This `10^6` is not what you think it is . `^` operator is bitwise XOR in c .`10^6` is not `1000000`.

If you print `10^6` it is equal to `12` , and no reason to crash .

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about this rule, haha. since 10^6 = 12, why does my array of size 14 have no compilation or runtime issues? and returns the correct answer? This is where I'm puzzled now...

Comment: @noknowledge You array has `12` elements , and I don't get why do you expect any compilation or runtime problems with it. It is a VLA which is  valid and you don't even do anything with it so what is correct answer ?

Comment: @noknowledge      Crash you get is because of array of `1000000` elements . Use dynamic allocation , or declare array `static` .

Comment: I get that. My array though has 14 elements. I am currently running my program, and using a set of data with 14 elements, but sticking with this 10^6 (which is allocating space for 12 elements), and am not running into any problems. I am even displaying the number of elements and have a total of 14 (0 - 13). It doesn't make since. Also running, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]), returns 123. Just curious, and not sure what the next best approach is.

Comment: @noknowledge Well, if you are access out of bounds index , then your program invokes _undefined behaviour_ and thus due to which may be working correct . But don't  rely on this which could be side effect of _UB_ .

Comment: that's what I was thinking, thanks a lot, you've been really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

^ is a bitwise operator not used for power (exponents)

Use the pow function. It takes doubles so you will.

Because you used the bitwise operator you never actually got that large a number. So the program never crashed.

Comment: Thanks for the help Nick!